# Selected Filename not showing in Label from one Form to another C#

Tags: c#, thumbnails

I am working modifying an application that will be an utility. The application is designed so far to load pictures from any folder and show them in thumbnails, then the user should be able to select those that will want to save in a database. The thumbnails consists of an `ImageViewer` form that will load each image. Thus, in the `ImageViewer` form there is a textbox and a `checkbox`. Each of them will be generated dynamically as many pictures are loaded (see the image below). The problem is that when clicking the `checkbox` it should show the name listed above the picture (thumbnail `textbox`) of the file in a `label` (it can be a `label` or `textbox`). Any time when the user clicks the `checkbox` will see a message saying: `'Added anyImage.jpg'` or when deselecting the checkbox will say `'Removed anyImage.jpg'`. It is not showing the text in the label. I have the following code.

**This code is to load the main form:**

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Login loginSystem = new Login();

    lbHowMany.Visible = false;
    lbHowMany.Text = "Images";
    lbNumberOfFiles.Visible = false;

    btnEnableViewer.Text = "Disable Viewer";

    this.buttonCancel.Enabled = false;

    //stripSelectedFile.Text = "";

    m_ImageDialog = new ImageDialog();

    m_AddImageDelegate = new DelegateAddImage(this.AddImage);

    m_Controller = new ThumbnailController();
    m_Controller.OnStart += new ThumbnailControllerEventHandler(m_Controller_OnStart);
    m_Controller.OnAdd += new ThumbnailControllerEventHandler(m_Controller_OnAdd);
    m_Controller.OnEnd += new ThumbnailControllerEventHandler(m_Controller_OnEnd);

    if (ImageViewer.sendSelectedFile != null)
    {
        stripSelectedFile.Text = ImageViewer.sendSelectedFile.ToString();
        txInformation.Text = ImageViewer.sendSelectedFile.ToString();
    }
}
```

**This other code is from the ImageViewer form checkbox:**

```
public void cboxToSave_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cboxToSave.Checked == true)
            {
                sendSelectedFile = "Added: " + txFileName.Text;    

            }
            else
            {
                {
                    sendSelectedFile = "Removed: " + txFileName.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the variable declared in the class that will send the selected file name to the main form: `public static string sendSelectedFile;`

[image: Checkbox not updating text in label]

**ImageViewer Code:**

```
public partial class ImageViewer : UserControl
    {
        private Image m_Image;
        private string m_ImageLocation;

        private bool m_IsThumbnail;
        private bool m_IsActive;

        public static string sendSelectedFile;
        public ImageViewer()
        {
            m_IsThumbnail = false;
            m_IsActive = false;

            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public Image Image
        {
            set
            {
                m_Image = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return m_Image;
            }
        }

        public string ImageLocation
        {
            set
            {
                m_ImageLocation = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return m_ImageLocation;
            }
        }

        public bool IsActive
        {
            set
            {
                m_IsActive = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            get
            {
                return m_IsActive;
            }
        }

        public bool IsThumbnail
        {
            set
            {
                m_IsThumbnail = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return m_IsThumbnail;
            }
        }
        public void ImageSizeChanged(object sender, ThumbnailImageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Width = e.Size;
            this.Height = e.Size;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        public void LoadImage(string imageFilename, int width, int height)
        {
            Image tempImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilename);
            m_ImageLocation = imageFilename;

            //gets the name of the file from the location
            txFileName.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFilename);

            int dw = tempImage.Width;
            int dh = tempImage.Height;
            int tw = width;
            int th = height;
            double zw = (tw / (double)dw);
            double zh = (th / (double)dh);
            double z = (zw <= zh) ? zw : zh;
            dw = (int)(dw * z);
            dh = (int)(dh * z);

            m_Image = new Bitmap(dw, dh);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(m_Image);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(tempImage, 0, 0, dw, dh);
            g.Dispose();

            tempImage.Dispose();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            if (g == null) return;
            if (m_Image == null) return;

            int dw = m_Image.Width;
            int dh = m_Image.Height;
            int tw = this.Width - 8; // remove border, 4*4 
            int th = this.Height - 8; // remove border, 4*4 
            double zw = (tw / (double)dw);
            double zh = (th / (double)dh);
            double z = (zw <= zh) ? zw : zh;

            dw = (int)(dw * z);
            dh = (int)(dh * z);
            int dl = 4 + (tw - dw) / 2; // add border 2*2
            int dt = 4 + (th - dh) / 2; // add border 2*2

            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Yellow), dl, dt, dw, dh);

            if (m_IsThumbnail)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    //draws and color the horizontal line in the miniature
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.LightSalmon),
                        new Point(dl + 3, dt + dh + 1 + j),
                        new Point(dl + dw + 3, dt + dh + 1 + j));
                    //draws and color the vertical right line in the miniature
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.LightGreen),
                        new Point(dl + dw + 1 + j, dt + 3),
                        new Point(dl + dw + 1 + j, dt + dh + 3));
                }

            g.DrawImage(m_Image, dl, dt, dw, dh);

            if (m_IsActive)
            {
                //draws the rectangle inside and gives it color
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.MediumTurquoise, 1), dl, dt, dw, dh);
                //draws the rectangle outside and gives it color
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.RosyBrown, 2), dl - 2, dt - 2, dw + 4, dh + 4);

            }
        }

        private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        public void cboxToSave_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cboxToSave.Checked == true)
            {
                sendSelectedFile = "Added: " + txFileName.Text;    

            }
            else
            {
                {
                    sendSelectedFile = "Removed: " + txFileName.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code in the `MainForm` that adds the images in the `flowLayoutPanelMain`**

```
delegate void DelegateAddImage(string imageFilename);
        private DelegateAddImage m_AddImageDelegate;
        private void AddImage(string imageFilename)
        {
            try
            {
                // thread safe
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(m_AddImageDelegate, imageFilename);
                }
                else
                {
                    int size = ImageSize;
                    lbNumberOfFiles.Visible = true;
                    lbHowMany.Visible = true;

                    ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer();

                    imageViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                    imageViewer.LoadImage(imageFilename, 256, 256);
                    imageViewer.Width = size;
                    imageViewer.Height = size;
                    imageViewer.IsThumbnail = true;

                    imageViewer.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(imageViewer_MouseClick);

                    txInformation.Text = imageFilename;
                    SetProgressBar();
                    counter++;
                    lbHowMany.Text = "Images";
                    lbNumberOfFiles.Text = counter.ToString();

                    this.OnImageSizeChanged += new ThumbnailImageEventHandler(imageViewer.ImageSizeChanged);
                    //passes the pictures to the main picture container 
                    this.flowLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(imageViewer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has ocurred. Error: " + e, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Instead of communicating via a static string, make your ImageViewer form raise a custom **Event** that the main form subscribes to.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I think I tried something like that before.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of the ImageViewer Form raising a custom event whenever the checkbox is changed:

```
public partial class ImageViewer : Form
{
    public ImageViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void dlgImageChecked(ImageViewer sender, string message);
    public event dlgImageChecked ImageChecked;

    private void cboxToSave_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageChecked != null)
        {
            ImageChecked(this, (cboxToSave.Checked ? "Added: " : "Removed: ") + txFileName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when you **create** instances of ImageViewer, you need to wire up that event...something like:

```
// ... in your MainForm class ...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // when you create your instances of ImageViewer, wire up their ImageChecked() event:
    ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer();
    iv.ImageChecked += Iv_ImageChecked;

}

private void Iv_ImageChecked(ImageViewer sender, string message)
{
    ImageViewer iv = (ImageViewer)sender; // if you need to reference it for other reasons ...

    stripSelectedFile.Text = message;
    txInformation.Text = message;
}
```

Your original post didn't show the creation of your ImageViewer instances so you'll need to incorporate the above somehow into your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the full code for the `ImageViewer` so you can see it. I still don't understand the function for 
`private void button1_Click`

Comment: The button1 code is simply showing that when you **create instances of ImageViewer** you need to wire up the event that I added to it.  Your code does not show how ImageViewer is being created, so I had to put that code somewhere.

Comment: I was able to follow the example you gave, but instead, using a timer set to interval of 100, and is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: A Timer is almost certainly the wrong approach...but okay.

Comment: Mr. @Idle_Mind, I tried the code above that you provided. I am still curious how to make it work in that way, but still can't get it. It works using the timer, but I can't find a way for it to update the label when you check/uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: I can help, but you need to show me the code that creates instances of ImageViewer.  You must be doing a loop **somewhere** that has `new ImageViewer()` in it somewhere!

Comment: If you see above in the description, I added the `ImageViewer` code, which is a different class. Is that what you need to see? In addition, I included the `private void AddImage(string imageFilename)`

Comment: In addition to that, could you teach me how to do a 'check/uncheck all' for the checkboxes in every image? As you can see, the `ImageViewer` is a child-form that is multiplied by the loop as many pictures are found in the folder. Sorry if I ask too much, I am learning this.